# Basic Grid Layout not Initializing or Running

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I'm trying to use cytoscape.js to display a graph on my page and I'm having a hard time just getting a basic instance to display properly.

Code Breakdown:

I get the graph elements via an AJAX call, pass the elements into the cytoscape constructor, and display the instance in a Bootstrap modal.

Here's my JavaScript:

```
var cy;

$.ajax({
                url : "getGraphElements",
                data : {
                    str : variableToGetCorrectGraphData
                },
                success : function(data) {
                    var elementsJson = JSON.parse(data.elements);
                    console.log(elementsJson);
                    
                    cy = cytoscape({
                        
                        container : document.getElementById('cy'),
                        
                        wheelSensitivity : 0.25,
                        
                        elements : elementsJson,
                        
                        style : [
                            {
                                selector: 'node',
                                style: 
                                {
                                    'background-color' : '#666',
                                    label : 'data(id)'
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                selector: 'edge',
                                style: 
                                {
                                    'width' : 3,
                                    'line-color' : '#737373',
                                    'target-arrow-color' : '#737373',
                                    'target-arrow-shape' : 'triangle',
                                    'curve-style' : 'bezier'
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        layout : {
                            name: 'grid',
                            fit: true,                                                  // whether to fit the viewport to the graph
                            padding: 0,                                                 // padding used on fit
                            avoidOverlap: true,                                         // prevents node overlap, may overflow boundingBox if not enough space
                            avoidOverlapPadding: 20,                                    // extra spacing around nodes when avoidOverlap: true
                            nodeDimensionsIncludeLabels: false,                         // Excludes the label when calculating node bounding boxes for the layout algorithm
                            condense: false,                                            // uses all available space on false, uses minimal space on true
                            sort: function(a,b) {                                       // a sorting function to order the nodes; e.g. function(a, b){ return a.data('weight') - b.data('weight') }
                                return a.degree() - b.degree();
                            }, 
                            animate: false,                                             // whether to transition the node positions
                            transform: function (node, position ){ return position; }   // transform a given node position. Useful for changing flow direction in discrete layouts 
                        }
                    });

                    $('#cyModal').modal('show');
                }
            });
        });
```

Here's my Bootstrap Modal :

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="cyModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="cyModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="cyModalLabel">Graph View</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="cy" style="height : 750px"></div>          
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's a sample of the JSON returned by the AJAX (although I'm almost certain this is not incorrect because all the elements appear to be present in the constructed graph) :

```
{ "nodes" : [{ "data" : { "id" : "12293"} }...], "edges" : [{ "data" : { "id" : "24607-26336", "source" : "24607", "target" : "26336" } }...] }
```

My Problem is that all the nodes appear stacked in the top left corner when the graph finishes initializing. I believe this is because the instance is using the `null` layout. A quick peek in the inspector console shows that `cy.layout.name = 'layout'`.

I just can't get it to initialize with the grid layout like I want it to. I've tried taking out the layout in the constructor, and using `cy.layout({name : 'grid',}).run();`. I've tried using both, one after the other. I've even tried putting `cy.layout({name : 'grid',}).run();` in a while loop until `cy.layout.name == 'grid'` - that just caused the page to freeze. I've tried changing basically every option in both the Cytoscape initializer and the Layout initializer - no dice. What I find weird is that when I execute `cy.layout({name : 'grid',}).run();` in the inspector console, the layout sets up properly...

If anyone has any ideas I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Using `undefined` as property values in your `layout` object prevents the default behavior. Remove all properties that you have defined as `undefined`.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Ok, just edited the Question with that suggestion, and tried running the code: still no dice. I also removed the options specifying animation controls, since I just set animate : false. Any other ideas?

Comment: why do you have an empty function declaration in `position` property?

Comment: @RandyCasburn No particular reason. All the options that I included were from the list of options for the grid layout provided by Cytoscape.js; I assumed that they were the 'default' options and just copied them all. I removed the empty function from ```position``` and still no change.

Comment: Ok, those are the things that stuck out to me. I don't know cytoscape so I'll defer to those experts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, OP here. I think my problem is with Bootstrap.

I started by noticing that I call `$('#cyModal').modal('show');` after I've finished initializing the Cytoscape instance. I realized that before I call `$('#cyModal').modal('show');` the `div` container for my Cytoscape instance has no size and is invisible. So I tried calling `$('#cyModal').modal('show');` before initializing Cytoscape, but that still didn't work. Furthermore, I noticed that the modal wasn't actually showing until after Cytoscape initialized.

Apparently, for this sort of thing, I need to wait for the Bootstrap modal to fire the 'shown' event before setting my Cytoscape layout to be sure that the `div` is visible and has a size. So I put my layout setter in a listener for `shown.bs.modal`:

```
$('#cyModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    cy.layout({
        name: 'grid',
        fit: true,                                                  // whether to fit the viewport to the graph
        padding: 0,                                                 // padding used on fit
        avoidOverlap: true,                                         // prevents node overlap, may overflow boundingBox if not enough space
        avoidOverlapPadding: 20,                                    // extra spacing around nodes when avoidOverlap: true
        nodeDimensionsIncludeLabels: false,                         // Excludes the label when calculating node bounding boxes for the layout algorithm
        condense: false,                                            // uses all available space on false, uses minimal space on true
        sort: function(a,b) {                                       // a sorting function to order the nodes; e.g. function(a, b){ return a.data('weight') - b.data('weight') }
            return a.degree() - b.degree();
        }, 
        animate: false,                                             // whether to transition the node positions
        transform: function (node, position ){ return position; }   // transform a given node position. Useful for changing flow direction in discrete layouts
     }).run();
});
```

This works for me, but it feels a bit like a hack - why can't I just do it like I originally wanted to? If that's just the way the cookie crumbles with Cytoscape.js and Bootstrap - c'est la vie; but I'll take any other suggestions if anyone has a more 'natural feeling' solution.